# Strings from command line won't print

Tags: c, console

All it does is give me back what I've imputed.  It doesn't actually print from the for loop in the program since I added extra line breaks just to test it and the line breaks don't show up:

The name of the file is string.c  It should print how are you doing but with extra spaces between each word. This is the command that I'm using in windows console:

string how are you doing

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int i;

 if(argc<2){
    printf("You didn't specify the arguments or paramters");
 }
else{


 for (i=1; i< argc; i++) {
     printf("%s ", argv[i]);
     printf("\n");
     printf("\n");
     printf("\n");
 }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `extra spaces between each word`... i don't think the code above can do this.

Comment: Perhaps you have another program that is named `string` in your system. Try `./string how are you doing?`.

Comment: Why not?  Also, I tried printing out another word after each  printf("%s ", argv[i]); statement and that word doesn't output in the console.

Comment: R Sahu, what would that command be for windows?

Comment: Something seems very broken with your environment then. I'm sorry I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: So, you took my code and it worked fine for you then?  As long as it's working then that's all I care about.  I can test it on another computer tomorrow.  Please respond.

Comment: It is working without any issue.

Comment: Can you please add to your question how do you call the compiler and how do you start your program?